# Get the users that used their card for N amount of times between 2 dates

Tags: mysql

I want to get the users(Gebruiker) that used their card(pas) for N amount of times between 2 dates.

Now I tried to use `HAVING COUNT` or some variation of that, to get the amount of times a row contains a foreign key and use that to filter out everyone that used it atleast 5 times between 2 dates.

This is what I tried but without the date:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(Pas_pasnummer)
FROM gebruiker
INNER JOIN pas_has_poort ON gebruiker.gebruikernummer=pas_has_poort.Pas_pasnummer
HAVING COUNT(Pas_pasnummer) = '1'
```

This is my database:
[image: Database model]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gebruiker.gebruikernummer` is not a foreign key to `pas_has_poort.Pas_pasnummer`. You need to go through the linking table `pas`.

You need to group the query by `gebruikernummer`.

Then you can put a condition on the date in `pas_has_poort`.

```
SELECT g.*, COUNT(*) AS use_count
FROM gebruiker AS g
JOIN pas AS p ON g.gebruikernummer = p.gebruikergebruikernummer
JOIN pas_has_poort AS pp ON p.pasnummer = pp.Pas_pasnummer
WHERE pp.inchecktijd BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
GROUP BY g.gebruikernummer
HAVING use_count >= 5
```

Comment: Thank you for that but this created another problem for me that I got duplicate keys in pas_has_poort how can I have duplicate keys or is there another solution for that?

Comment: Duplicate keys are OK there. You can use the same card at the same port at different times.

Comment: I added inchecktijd as an extra primary key and that made it special each entry.